# Overriding hashCode and operator== in subclasses

Tags: dart

Let's say I have this code in a class:

```
abstract class ClassA {
  final int a;
  final double b;
  const ClassA(this.a, this.b);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    if (other is ClassA) {
      return runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          a == other.a &&
          b == other.b;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    var result = 17;

    result = 37 * result + a.hashCode;
    result = 37 * result + b.hashCode;

    return result;
  }

}
```

And now I want to create a two concrete classes B and C like so:

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {
  ClassB() : super(0, 0.0);
}

class ClassC extends ClassA {
  final int c;
  ClassC(this.c) : super(0, 0.0);
}
```

For sure, `ClassB` is ok because it just extends `ClassA` without introducing any new variable. But what for `ClassC`? There is a new c parameter so should I override hashCode and == again? Like this:

```
class ClassC extends ClassA {
  final int c;
  ClassC(this.c) : super(0, 0.0);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    if (other is ClassC) {
      return runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          c == other.c &&
          super == other;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    var result = 17;

    result = 37 * result + a.hashCode;
    result = 37 * result + super.hashCode;

    return result;
  }
}
```

Please notice how in `ClassC` I have added calls to super. Is

```
result = 37 * result + super.hashCode;
```

needed?

Comment: You can reason this out yourself.  Why *wouldn't* `ClassC` need its own `operator ==` and `hashCode` implementations?  How would `operator ==` and `hashCode` account for the value of `c` otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, needed.  unless two objects with different values for C should be ignored for equality.  Also, your hashCode for C doesn't use all the members, so it might skew hash-based data structures.